# Stripping non whitespace character from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I hv a pandas dataframe and in that one column has string values. The data type of the column says object as it is a series.

But one of the values is

```
RPT_EDUCATE--
```

Now I am trying to remove the end "--". So I do

```
series.str.strip("--").
```

But it doesn't remove the trailing hyphens from it. The same works if I try it on a string

```
s="""RPT_EDUCATE--"""

s.strip("--")

'RPT_EDUCATE'
```

Comment: check the type of dataframe

Comment: It is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Plus I am trying this on the series inside.

Comment: Works for me: `s = pd.Series(['RPT_EDUCATE--']); s = s.str.strip('--')` gives me a stripped series

Comment: Just realized after looking closely that there was a space in the end too after -- in data. Now I added strip("-- "). Works. Thnx

Comment: Note that `strip` takes the *characters*, not the sequences you want to strip as an argument. So `s = s.str.strip('-')` will do what you want as well (remove all `-`, even if they are consecutive, from the end)